# apache.commons.io.IOUtils throw out of memory error

Tags: android, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I'm using the following code to get the string representation  of server response.  The problem is that it's throwing an out of memory exception when it tries to pass the response `toString()`. This code is running on Android.

```java
String resp = IOUtils.toString(resEntity.getContent(), "UTF-8");

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
if (resEntity != null) {
  //String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
  String resp = IOUtils.toString(resEntity.getContent(), "UTF-8"); // exception here
  Log.i(TAG, resp);
// ........
// gosn parser code here
// ........
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=47395KB, Allocated=36544KB)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter.write(SourceFile:138)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(SourceFile:2002)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(SourceFile:1980)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(SourceFile:1957)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(SourceFile:1907)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(SourceFile:778)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(SourceFile:803)
```

Comment: This code isn't causing the OOM, unless you're downloading a large file (in which case you may need to download it to a file and read the file in chunks). Something else is using your memory.

Comment: how big is your json?

Comment: I'm building a android app which is collection of widgets, each widget  properties can change from CMS, When the application start it's downloading the all the widget changes and store in the SQLite data base. In that case I cannot exactly say what's the file size. Also this app use set of images saved in database to show as app backgorund images, Is there any way that i can read chunk of response